# Utilizar tasks síncronas ou assíncronas para coletar contadores de impressao

Tags: c#, task

Estou tentando desenvolver um processo que realiza a coleta de alguns contadores de impressoras via protocolo SNMP, pensei em utilizar Threads para realizar este processo, refatorei para utilizar tasks, porém não sei se deveria utilizar um async await para esta tarefa, neste caso me pego meio confuso se estou desenvolvendo este método da melhor maneira. Segue código do método:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ImpressoraDAO dao = new ImpressoraDAO())
        {
            var impressoras = dao.Listar().ToList();
            var impressorasTasks = impressoras.Select(impressora =>
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (impressora.IsConected())
                    {
                        using (ContadorDAO contadorDao = new ContadorDAO())
                        {
                            var contador = new Contador();
                            contador.Id = DateTime.Now;
                            contador.ImpressoraId = impressora.Id;
                            contador.QuantidadePaginas = Convert.ToInt64(OperacaoSNMP.ObterObjetoOID(IPAddress.Parse(impressora.Ip), OID.CONTADADOR_TOTAL));
                            contadorDao.Adicionar(contador);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }).ToArray();

            Task.WhenAll(impressorasTasks);
        }
    }
```

Como posso melhorar este código ? Devo deixá-lo assim ou seria melhor utilizar um async await ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso pode ser melhor nem usar `Task`. As tasks funcionam melhor quando voce tem operacoes de `I\O` assincronas. Porque enquanto o `I\O` nao for processado o CPU pode continuar a fazer outras coisas.

Uma coisa que reparei é que o método `contadorDao.Adicionar(contador)` poderá estar mal implementado. Eu nao sei o que esse método faz. Mas se ele fizer uma consulta no banco de dados entao faria sentido ele ser assincrono. E ai voce deveria usar tasks.

Uma abordagem melhor para o código atual seria usar o [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var impressoras = dao.Listar().ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(impressoras, impressora => {
    if (impressora.IsConected())
    {
        using (ContadorDAO contadorDao = new ContadorDAO())
        {
            var contador = new Contador();
            contador.Id = DateTime.Now;
            contador.ImpressoraId = impressora.Id;
            contador.QuantidadePaginas = Convert.ToInt64(OperacaoSNMP.ObterObjetoOID(IPAddress.Parse(impressora.Ip), OID.CONTADADOR_TOTAL));
            contadorDao.Adicionar(contador);
        }
    }
});
```

Em último caso vai ter que recorrer a técnicas de profilling para ver qual é a abordagem com o desempenho melhor para o seu cenário.

Comment: Na Verdade as minhas classes DAO são somente uma camada entre o EntityFrameworkCore e a regra de negócio, dentro do contador eu utilizo o context pra inserir esse contador em um banco de dados! O contador tem uma chave composta pelo id da impressora e a hora da coleta! Espero ter esclarecido essa questão ! Sendo assim é melhor usar async ?

Comment: @LucasBarbosa Sim. Mas para isso voce tem que usar o `SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: Irei refatorar o código seguindo esse conselho Bruno pra ver como se comportara e ver se realmente peguei a idéia! E gostaria de agradece-lo desde já!